# PowerShell ZIP file - Create local then copy OR direct to network?

Tags: powershell

I'm creating an archive on a network share for the purposes of backup.

What is PowerShell / Windows doing differently behind the scenes if I create the zip file locally before copying VS. using the network path directly?

Option A

```
Compress-Archive -Path C:\Something -DestinationPath \\server\share\file.zip
```

Option B

```
Compress-Archive -Path C:\Something -DestinationPath C:\file.zip
Move-Item C:\file.zip $networkpath
```

Comment: Have you tried it and found a material difference? Not sure what you're trying to ask here that can't be answered by trying it for yourself.

Comment: Network bandwidth is usually the bottleneck in operations like this, so you want to minimize the amount of data being transferred. Meaning you want to compress the data locally, then copy the compressed (and thus smaller) file.

Comment: I know that, which is why I want to know if Option A does this or not.

Comment: Then how about you simply test it and compare the numbers?

Comment: What simple test are you talking about?  I don't know how to measure the bandwidth use of a single process over time on Windows.

Comment: When in doubt, read the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/3.0/microsoft.powershell.utility/measure-command). Re-run each command a couple times to compensate caching, etc. and calculate the average per command. If one takes less time than the other, you have the answer to your question.

Answer (score 4):

I used Measure-Command to test both cases.  This doesn't give any academic information about what is happening behind the scenes or answer the original question, but it is very useful.

**Option A** required 277 seconds to complete.

**Option B** required 156 seconds to complete.

- 116 seconds to produce the zip file locally.
- 40 seconds for transferring the file to a network share.